# Adding charts to a matplotlib subgrid

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following Matplotlib figure, with 2 charts:
[image]

That i created with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=155, figsize=(8, 4))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0), facecolor='#131722')
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,1), facecolor='#131722')
```

Now i would like to add two charts, so `ax3` and ax4, each needs to be below the two charts, they should have the same width of the two charts but half the height of the two bigger charts. How can i do that? I tried various solutions from here [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec01.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-demo-gridspec01-py) but i'm struggling to get the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `gridspec_kw` argument of `plt.subplots`. This allows you to specify the dimensions of the grid (in this case 2x2) and the ratio of the heights:

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2 , gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": [2, 1]})
for cAx in ax.flatten():
    cAx.set_facecolor('#131722')
f.savefig("test.png", facecolor='#131722')
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also create a 3x2 grid and specify that the first two subplots need to span two rows:

```py
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=155, figsize=(8, 6))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,0), facecolor='#131722', rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,1), facecolor='#131722', rowspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (2,0), facecolor='#131722')
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (2,1), facecolor='#131722')
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you a lot! I should really start using gridspec, looks way easier to use